# Java double URL Reader?

Tags: java

Can anyone help me with the Java URL reader?

I have created an URL reader in Java that reads the link and sends it to a specific file. 
How can I make the code read from two URL's and save it into a specific file ?

Here is my code :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    yc.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    BufferedWriter psout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\final.txt"));
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    psout.write(inputLine);
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    psout.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the content from both URLs saved into one file, one after the other? Or each URL saved into a separate file?

Comment: I think you should (a) provide more clarity about what you want and (b) show what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to write to a single file, you could extract this out into a method and use the `append` argument in `FileWriter`:

```
private static void saveURL(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
   URL url = new URL(urlString);
   URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

   String inputLine;
   BufferedWriter psout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("final.txt", true));

   // write file...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, you want to write contents from two different URL's into the same file. you can have a List of URL objects and then read from/write iterating over the list.

```
List<URL> al = new ArrayList<>();
      URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
      URL google =new  URL("http://www.google.com");
      al.add(oracle);
      al.add(google);
      BufferedReader in=null;
      BufferedWriter psout=null;
      for(URL url: al){
      URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      yc.getInputStream()));
      String inputLine;
     psout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("final.txt"));
      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
      psout.write(inputLine);
      System.out.println(inputLine);
      }

      }      in.close();
      psout.close();
```